# How to create mulitple lagged variables over a grouped time series?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I've found the solution to this question for either grouped lags or lagging one group multiple times, but not both. For this example, I'd like to use the following dataframe:

```r
df <- data.frame(doy = rep((1:2), each = 6), years = rep(2017:2022), var = rnorm(6))
```

How can I create multiple lags (`lvar1`, `lvar2`, `lvar3`) that exist for two different groups, so that the result is that my 2017 group 2 does not have the lagged variable for 2022 in group 1?

Comment: I don't understand: *"my 2017 group 2 does not have the lagged variable for 2022 in group 1"*. Could you provide your expected output? Do you mean `lvar1 = lag(var, 1), lvar2 = lag(var, 2)` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

library(dplyr)

```
df <- data.frame(doy = rep((1:2), each = 6), years = rep(2017:2022), var = rnorm(6))

lag_fn <- list()
lags <- 1:10

for(i in lags) {
  
  fixer <- function(x, i) { 
    force(i) 
    return(
      function(x) {
        return(dplyr::lag(x, i))
      }
    )}
  
  lag_fn[[i]] <- fixer(x, i)
}


df %>% group_by('your_group_column') %>%  
  mutate(across("your_value_column", lag_fn, .names = "lag_{.fn}"))
```

BR